# echo is blank when using include statement

Tags: php, include, echo

I wanted to try out an example you can find here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php, 
but I can't seem to be able to make it work.

In a first file, index1.php, I put this:

```
<?php

$color = 'green';
$fruit = 'apple';

?>
```

In the second file,index2.php, I put this:

```
<?php

include("http://www.domain.com/mypathtothefile/index2.php"); 
echo "A $color $fruit";

?>
```

It should echo 'A green apple', but it echos nothing.
The path is correct though, since when I put the echo part in the first file (index1.php), then it does echo 'A geen apple', both in index1.php as index2.php.

Hope someone can help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the PHP configuration on your server set to allow the connection? Sorry I forgot what it was called, but you have to set it so that the file can be included like this.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `include("http://www.domain.com/mypathtothefile/index1.php");`? In your current code you're including `index2.php` into itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it just be:

```
include('index1.php');
```

**Edit:** corrected to reflect file names.

Comment: Damn. It works! Been looking for hours for it. Thanks! Do you know why the full path doesn't work?

Comment: The full path would work if you were actually providing a path. You are providing a URI. Pretty sure PHP wont attempt to load the file over HTTP when you issue `include` with a URI, but if it did, your server would output the result of evaluating the file anyway -- not the file itself (depending on configuration, of course).

Comment: You should have a relative or absolute file path and not the URL to include a file. Having the URL would not actually include the code, but the generated code displayed when you go to the URL.

Comment: In other words, if you used `include('/mypathtothefile/index1.php')` it would work.

Comment: O I see. First day of learning php so sorry for the stupid errors. Thanks again for your help.